# How to check if field value exists in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a form on a users page that calls a method, 'newDiscussion' to create a new discussion object between the logged in user (hereafter: user1) and the user whose page they're on (hereafter: user2). It also created a message object with a discussionId matching the newly created discussion object.

In the discussion object, I store user1._id and user2._id.

I want check whether an existing discussion object contains these two users Id's. If false, proceed as above, else just insert the message and make the discussionId match the existing discussion object Id.

Comment: How about you upsert that discussion?

Comment: I need to find the discussion first - this is to stop creating another discussion that already has the two user Id's in it.

Comment: Without any code it's impossible to give any real help.  In theory, create a variable to hold the discussion, parse the existing discussion objects and look for those 2 ids.  If you find them then populate the discussion var you just made and exit the loop.  After the loop, if the discussion object is undefined then instantiate it as a discussion object.

Comment: You can find or create in a single operation. Check this out: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the discussion published to your client, you can use [collection.findOne](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) method in your client code like this

```
var dicussion = Discussions.findOne({'user1._id': Meteor.userId(), 'user2._id': 'another user id'});

if (discussion) {
    // do some updates, if necessary
}
else {
    // else create a new discussion
}
```

Comment: Does findOne return a true/false or the found document object? I'm using your code and something strange is happening, both the if and else statements are being executed. To make things simple while I try and figure this out, the if statement is console.log('Discussion exists') and else console.log('No discussion'). But when I call this method (this is server side code) the if statement outputs onto the Meteor console log and the else statement outputs to the browser console. Here's the entire Meteor.methods code - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xLue5xqt/) - thanks for your help while I learn!

Comment: First thing to note is that the client is trying to do an optimistic run of your method. This is probably because you defined your method in a shared location (meaning its visible to both the server and the client). The client is running the method optimistically, but will still wait for the response from the server. In your case, the client doesn't have the Discussion document in it's minimongo (we'll need to use pub/sub to fix this), but the server always has access to the Discussions collection. Now, we need to discuss what you want to return to your browser (e.g. the document or boolean)

Comment: If you want to return the document, you should use the publish/subscribe Meteor functions; otherwise, you could just return true/false, and the client can respond accordingly. Here's something to consider when you make your decision... Meteor does a unique username validation server side (using Meteor.methods) and returns a true/false value to the client instead of the user document. This is preferred because they do not want to expose the user document to the client.